# How to write a legend template in angular2 with primeNG

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am using angular2 with primeNG. I want to set custom legends for the bar charts and pie charts. I wish to know how to write a legendTemplate (this is a attribute of bar charts).My code looks like this(as below)

code in graph.component.html----

```
<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <div class="ui-grid-row">
        <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
            <h3 class="first">Data Collected (By categories)</h3>
            <p-pieChart [value]="data2" width="300" height="300" (onSegmentsSelect)="onSegmentClick($event)"
                        [segmentShowStroke]="false" [animationSteps]="50" animationEasing="easeInOutQuint" 
                        [animateScale]="true" [legend]="Comedy" [legend]="lgnd1" [legendTemplate]="template"></p-pieChart>
        </div>
        <div #lgnd1></div>
        <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
         <p-barChart [value]="data" width="640" height="320" [legend]="lgnd"></p-barChart>
            <div #lgnd></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

code in graphComponent.ts

```
constructor() {
               this.data2 = [{
                        value: 125,
                        color: '#2196F3',
                        highlight: '#64B5F6',
                        label: 'Comedy'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 50,
                        color: '#673AB7',
                        highlight: '#9575CD',
                        label: 'Drama'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 75,
                        color: '#00897B',
                        highlight: '#26A69A',
                        label: 'Action'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 22,
                        color: '#FF9800',
                        highlight: '#FFB74D',
                        label: 'Romance'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 100,
                        color: '#FF5722',
                        highlight: '#FF8A65',
                        label: 'Sci-fi'
                    }];
              this.data = {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'My First dataset',
                    fillColor: '#42A5F5',
                    strokeColor: '#1E88E5',
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                },
                {
                    label: 'My Second dataset',
                    fillColor: '#9CCC65',
                    strokeColor: '#7CB342',
                    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: PrimeNG has updated to charts 2.x in upcoming beta7, it draws legends automatically.

Comment: @CagatayCivici phew :-) just started using this and can't find any css with `.pie-legend` defined. you're saying it's now all done within the canvas? that's great!

Comment: hopefully it can put data labels ON a piechart itself too :-)

Comment: beta.7 is out now with new demos including a legend. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/piechart For datalabels, I think you need to check charts.js 2.x docs to see if it is supported.

Comment: Any help on how to write a custom legend???